# Form inputs in one line

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have grouped 3 inputs in one line ([bootply](http://www.bootply.com/pTmsLKcFqr))

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group has-warning">
          <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 control-label">name</label>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">                      
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="order">
          </div>


          <label for="inputWarning1" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-3 control-label">quantity</label>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control " placeholder="quantity" name="quantity" id="inputWarning1">
          </div>


          <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-3 control-label">####</label>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">                      
            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="AA" name="packetNumber">
          </div>

      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and I want only the input with quantity has the color of the class `has-warning`. Is there a way to do that by keeping 3 inputs in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `has-warning` class from the div which has class `form-group` and put a separate div above the *quantity* lable like below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 control-label">name</label>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">                      
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="order">
          </div>

          <div class="has-warning">
             <label for="inputWarning1" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-3 control-label">quantity</label>
             <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
               <input type="number" class="form-control " placeholder="quantity" name="quantity" id="inputWarning1">
             </div>
          </div>


          <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-3 control-label">####</label>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">                      
            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="AA" name="packetNumber">
          </div>

      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edited Code In Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/3JijrnKLZZ)

Check It.